# xAxis label is not visible properly in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

if I have a large amount of data then the `xAxis` label is not showing properly. you can see in this code: https://jsfiddle.net/4nvmuc25/127/

if I have a low amount of data then it's fine my `xAxis` label is showing correctly.

so I want to show the xAxis label properly if I have a large amount of data.

`Restriction`: `1`:you can't change the rotation property for `xAxis`.
`2`:`xAxis` labels should not intercept each other.
`3`:you can't do by css.

`Not restriction`: you can set `tickInterval`, `step` property in `xAxis` but remember the amount of data is dynamic, it could be any number.

Comment: can x-axis labels in two lines?

Comment: nope we can`t do this because labels is only one word (like Jan-21). if we break it then its not readble for users

Comment: okay there is no enough space for the labels of such fonts to fit in either break or decrease the font size or increase the width of the chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use category x-axis type in this case. In API we can read:

> **step: number**
>
> ...
> By default, when 0, the step is calculated automatically to avoid
> overlap. To prevent this, set it to 1. This usually only happens on a
> category axis, and is often a sign that you have chosen the wrong axis
> type.

As a solution use linear axis with a custom formatter function for labels:

```
const labels = [
    "Apr-1",
    "May-2",
    ...
];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        labels: {
            ...,
            formatter: function() {
                return labels[this.pos]
            }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lk8aogpq/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels